# Extract and match multiple rows in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, salesforce, data-manipulation, data-management

I'm in Google sheets, attempting to assign the correct Salesforce Account IDs to a LONG list of accounts. I have exported all accounts with IDs, and in another sheet I have a list of opportunities I need to import with DataLoader. However, in order to attach these opportunities to their accounts, they need to have the Account ID.

Essentially I need to take Account Name from each sheet, take the corresponding ID and assign that ID to both Account Names. I am not a developer but I am a Salesforce Admin which does require some basic formula building and I'm more than willing to give anything a shot in order to not have to match them manually, one-by-one. Thanks.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

You need [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en-GB).

Reorder your columns so the Account Name comes first, then Id. Optionally sort by Name, performance will be better. Think what you'll want to do with duplicate accounts.

```
=VLOOKUP(E2;$A$2:$B$14;2;false)
```

[image]

the parameters are

1. which value,
2. against what range (putting dollar signs helps fix the range, otherwise as you drag the formula down it might drag the range down too),
3. cell from which column to return,
4. is the reference table sorted

Comment: This looks like it can only match a few at a time, but maybe I'm not fully grasping the concept. Can this match a list of over 100 to a list of over 10k? Obviously they won't all have matches but that's fine, I just need the ones that DO match in order to get that Account ID quickly.

Comment: sure, it should match. As you drag the column down make sure the range of account names and ids stays in place (dollar signs or maybe make it select whole columns, not just a rectangle). And if you didn't sort the accounts by name - make sure the 4th parameter is "false". It's optional but important

Comment: I have figured this out but now it's repeating certain IDs. It's not because there isn't a match, and I can't figure out why it's behaving like this.

Comment: Did you put "false" as 4th parameter? Any chance for some minimal reproducible example you can share?

Comment: Here's a link to a simplified version of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A-S0nHFIUGycaDo7KDPAzWBwRZQmfxkjaMivwGfBh-8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wAuSml1Jc4p0rjszJl0eYwPGcq5o0QwlHnSMQeVZzxQ/edit?usp=sharing